# Margin display disparity between IE7 and FF3

Tags: html, css

Refer to HTML, CSS below.

Why the margin-bottom will not reflect in IE7, but in FF3? Is there any workaround for it?

Notice that I set margin: 50 in CSS.

```
<body style="background-color:#fff">
<div class="window">
  d-window
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{margin:10px;padding:0;background-color:#1e1e1e;color:#ddd; border: 1px solid #000000}
.window { width:280px; clear:both; margin: 50px; border: 1px solid #000000}
```

Thanks

Comment: You missed the closing ;  in your body style. And there is no margin-bottom in your CSS.

Comment: margin alone already included margin-top, left, right and bottom

Answer (score 1):

use a #container div instead of the body and use float on the container but not the .window class that should solve the problem.